# Counting male and Female in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am stuck with counting Male and Female, and I am not sure if anyone is able to help with that. My intention is to know " how many women and men have value "1" in cells A to D.

```
Sex  A  B  C  D

f    1  2  3  4
m    2  1  1  4
f    1  2  3  1
m    2  3  1  6
m    2  2  2  6
f    3  1  2  6
m    1  2  3  6
m    1  1  1  6
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify the counting rules.  Is the count 1 if any one or more 1s appear in A:D, or multiple 1s in A:D are each counted?  Are you looking for separate M and F subtotals?

Answer (score 2):

I am going to be using your spreadshet you screenshot to make it easy for you.

Let's say you are going to use cell `D15` to count the males with 1 in column A within your table as indicated within the spreadsheet you have screenshot, you would need to enter into cell `D15` the following formula

`=COUNTIFS(D3:D12,"=1",$C$3:$C$12,"=m")`

This could be replicated into cells `E15` to `G15` afterwards by selecting cell `D15` and dragging the handle across.

For counting females in the column with the value of 1, just change the formula to

`=COUNTIFS(D3:D12,"=1",$C$3:$C$12,"=f")`

The first part of the formula checks for a 1 and the second part looks for the sex of the 1 value.

Of course to get a total number of males/females in the table you could use a `SUM()` formula to total them up.

Say the males were in cells `D15` to `G15` you could have `=SUM(D15:G15)` in cell `H15`

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(D$4:G$11 = 1)*--(C$4:C$11 = I4))
```

[image]

Comment: This is not using the data set @Sovanny has in the spreadsheet screenshot

Comment: @Chris: I used the data he had in the table, instead. He put one set of data in the table and one set in the screenshot, and I chose the first one presented.

Comment: FWIW: You do not need the `--` in front of each Boolean test.  The simple act of multiplying them together will switch the TRUE/FALSE to 1/0

Comment: @Scott good to know, I think it's just a habit at this point when working with Excel arrays - appreciate the pointer :)

Comment: You guys are amazing. Thanks you so much, esp Joe.